# Inferring type in queries instead of string predicates in Realm Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I'm considering moving from my Core Data wrapper to Realm for my app and one thing that's nagging is how Realm uses strings for their predicates instead of inferring the type in their queries.

For example, why do I have to do this:

`Realm().objects(Dog).filter("age < 5").sorted("name")`

Instead of the Swift way like this:

`Realm().objects(Dog).filter { $0.age < 5 }.sorted { $0.name }`

And I missing something, or is this really how you use Realm for Swift?

Comment: Where are the realm docs regarding these methods?

Comment: In the queries section: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Answer (score 3):

Using Swift's built-in collection filtering methods is less efficient than using Realm's `NSPredicate` interface for querying.

A key reason that Swift's built-in collection filtering is less efficient is that it requires allocating a Swift object for each object stored in the Realm. This is necessary as a Swift object must exist in memory for Swift to evaluate expressions such as `$0.age < 5`. Using `NSPredicate` allows Realm to translate the predicate into an internal query format that can be evaluated directly against the properties stored in the Realm, without allocating instances of the Swift model classes. The instances can then be lazily allocated as objects in the result set are accessed.

Realm's query execution engine can also perform more optimizations when it understands the semantics of the query being performed. For instance, indexes can be used to more efficiently execute queries when indexed properties are used. If the predicate were a Swift closure its behavior would be opaque to Realm, preventing these optimizations.

It's worth pointing out that `NSPredicate` is used for queries by Core Data too, for very similar reasons.